# Doubt in Work-energy theorem relative to centre of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, work, inertial-frames

I have read these lines in a book

*Work done by total forces(internal or external) is equal to change in kinetic energy of the system with respect to centre of mass.*

Basically $W_1=\Delta KE$_{w.r.t CM}

Also i know

$KE_{total}$ ( from any frame of reference)$=KE_{w.r.t. CM}+KE_{CM}$.

Now what if we observe the system from another external reference frame, from whose POV centre of mass has some velocity and here we apply an external force which changes the velocity of centre of mass(thus ke of centre of mass) and also changes the ke with respect to centre of mass of system then this entire change according to me is equal to the work done by this force.
$W_2=ΔKE_{cm}+ΔKE_{system wrt cm}$

But $ΔKE_{system wrt cm}$ depends on relative velocity of particle(which is independent of F.O.R.) hence in both W1 and W2 this factor is same so clearly W1 is not equal to W2, so why on changing frame of references we obtain 2 different amount of work done?
I know about the fact that work done is relative but, how exactly is it relative in this case.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake in the first line. The work done on a system of particles is equal to $\Delta K_{e,total}$, because a net external force changes the velocity of the COM and thus changes the $K_{e, com}$ so $W_1 = \Delta K_{e, com} + \Delta K_{e, wrt com}$. Does this help you out?

Comment: @QuirkyTurtle98 i just went by the defination of the book, and logically if i am observing external force from CM's frame of reference, that external force cannot change the CM's motion because by defination of frame of reference we take CM's motion as always zero.

Comment: I didn't get your problem, Work is relative and it is coming out to be unequal in both frames so what's the issue. Displacements of particles are different in both the frames hence work is also different in both the frames.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the velocity of CM , it would become a non-inertial frame of reference relative to which you can't apply Newton's laws.
So now you have to apply pseudo forces to the particles and then find out their motion and the relative velocities after that. So you're saying that `hence in both W1 and W2 this factor is same' is not true.

Comment: The CM system becomes non-inertial only if it is accelerating.

Answer (score 0):

The energy found “relative to the center of mass” is measured in an inertial frame which is moving with the CM.
The energy associated with the motion of the CM is found using the total mass and the velocity of the center of mass (in some external frame). This will change if you change the external frame.

Answer (score -1):

I think your first expression (W1=ΔKE_{w.r.t CM})is true only if external force is 0 because in this case kinetic energy of com remain constant and change of kinetic energe not include the 1/2 mV2cm( here m is total mass of system; Vcm is velocity of com)

Comment: Hello Aditya, welcome to physics.SE! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/289977). Thanks!